# How do i take user input from discord and store it as a variable to use in an equation? Discord.py

Tags: python, variables, discord, discord.py

Ok so im not intierly fluent in discord.py but heres the code im trying to use:

```
from discord import channel
from discord.embeds import Embed
import discord
from discord.ext import *
import os
import random
import string
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import sys
import threading
from discord.utils import get
import discord
import asyncio
from threading import Thread
from keep_alive import keep_alive

load_dotenv()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

def init():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(bot.run(token))
    Thread(target=loop.run_forever).start()
    
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Bot is up and running')


@bot.command()
async def p(ctx):
  # MESSAGE 1, should have user input stored in variable "place"
  embed=discord.Embed()
  embed.add_field(name="Where did you place?", value="** **")
  sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

  # MESSAGE 2, should have user input stored in variable "kills"
  embed=discord.Embed()
  embed.add_field(name="How many kills did you get?", value="** **")
  sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

  # MESSAGE 3, should have combined input of place + kills AFTER running PLACEMENT CALC in variable "total""
  embed=discord.Embed()
  embed.add_field(name="Total Points:", value=total)
  sent = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

bot.run("OTA0MDc5MzY5NzU1MDU4MjA2.YX2Thg.S4A2e9SqZUvYZpyTzBW44W4Vumk")
keep_alive()
init()
```

I want to take the user response from the first and second msgs from discord.py and input them into the first 2 questions of this code so i can claculate the total:

```
import sys

# Placement input, should be response to MESSAGE 1 In discord.py
print ("Where did you place? ")
place = int(input('| \n'))

#Checking if place is in range from 20-1, Should respond with the message in an embed in discord
if place >20 or place <1:
    place = 0

# Kill input, response to MESSAGE 2 In discord.py
print ("How many kills did you get?")
kills = int(input('| \n '))


# Assigning total / final variable
total = 0
tplace = 0

# ranges for placement variables
top20 = (18,19,20)      #Top 20
top17 = (16,17)         #Top 17
top15 = (13,14,15)      #Top 15
top12 = (11,12)         #Top 12
top10 = (6,7,8,9,10)    #Top 10

#Total kills calculations
kills = kills * 10
    
#Total placement calculations
if place in top20: #Top 20
    tplace = 10
    
if place in top17: #Top 17
    tplace = 20
    
if place in top15: #Top 15
    tplace = 35
    
if place in top12: #Top 12
    tplace = 50
    
if place in top10: #Top 10
    tplace = 60

if place == 5: #Top 5
    tplace = 80
    
if place == 4: #Top 4
    tplace = 90
    
if place == 3: #Top 3
    tplace = 100
    
if place == 2: #Top 2
    tplace = 125    
    
if place == 1: #Top 1 / vic roy
    tlace = 175

#Output, should be MESSAGE 3 In discord.py
total = kills + tplace
print ("Total Points: ")
print (total)
```

and after calculating the total I just send the variable "total" inside of an emebd, i just dont know hwo to store the response to 2 separate discord message inside of the variables i need.
It should run as

```
Bot: "Where did you place?" 
you: 10 (Stored in variable "place")

Bot:"How many kills did you get?" 
you: 1 (Stored in variable "kills")

---------calculating the total points (should be 70)-------

Bot: "Total points: 70"
```

I know im probably being stupid but nothing i find online rlly helps

Comment: You should generate a new token as this one can be used by anyone now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some features for your embed to make it look better and used [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) to wait for user input.

```py
def calculate_points(place, kills):
    place_pt = 0

    if place in (18,19,20): #Top 20
        place_pt = 10
        
    elif place in (16,17): #Top 17
        place_pt = 20
        
    elif place in (13,14,15): #Top 15
        place_pt = 35
        
    elif place in (11,12): #Top 12
        place_pt = 50
        
    elif place in (6,7,8,9,10): #Top 10
        place_pt = 60

    elif place == 5: #Top 5
        place_pt = 80
        
    elif place == 4: #Top 4
        place_pt = 90
        
    elif place == 3: #Top 3
        place_pt = 100
        
    elif place == 2: #Top 2
        place_pt = 125    
        
    elif place == 1: #Top 1
        place_pt = 175

    kills_pt = kills * 10
    return place_pt + kills_pt # returning total points

async def message(ctx, message : str, timeout: float):
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
        
    question = await ctx.send(message)
    response = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=timeout)
    await question.delete()
    await response.delete()

    return int(response.content)

@bot.command()
async def p(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    
    try:
        place = await message(ctx, f"{ctx.author.mention} Where did you place?", timeout=60.0)
        kills = await message(ctx, f"{ctx.author.mention} How many kills did you get?", timeout=60.0)

    except Exception as e: # error handler
        if isinstance(e, asyncio.TimeoutError): # if timeout limit is exceeded
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} You were too slow to answer!")
        elif isinstance(e, ValueError): # if you use something else than number (when asked for kills and place)
            await ctx.send("Incorrect value!")
        
    else:
        total = calculate_points(place, kills) # invoking function that calculates place points

        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author}'s points")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="Place:", value=place, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Kills:", value=kills, inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Total points:", value=total, inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

### Results:

[image: results]

Comment: Is there a way to delete the command useage?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean? How else do you want to start function and give the input?

Comment: I mean as i use the !p command to start the function, and when the function is complete, we delete the !p usage, to reduce how many chats are there to clean it up

Comment: Yes, you can.  Do you want to delete other messages too (questions and answers) and leave only the last embed?

Comment: yeah that would make it look cleaner, can we also add date/time

Comment: I edited my answer it should work as you expect.

Comment: some of the unnessisary code you removed is used to keep the bot up and running on repel-it 24/7, but i appreiciate the help!! im going to try to write a new bot now that ik how to store variables and delete responses, thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[wait_for()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)** function.
I have written a function below which allows you get some data from user.

```py
import asyncio

async def prompt(ctx, message: str, timeout: float) -> str:
    await ctx.send(message)
    message = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel, timeout=timeout)
    return message.content
```

Let's use it for your command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def calculate(ctx):
    try:
        place = await prompt(ctx, "Where did you place?", timeout=10)
        kills = await prompt(ctx, "How many kills did you get?", timeout=10)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("You are too slow.")  # if time limit exceeded
    else:
        await ctx.send(calculate_score(place, kills))  # now you can calculate total score and send the result using input data (`place`, `kills`)
```

Comment: where would i put this in my current discord.py code? do i need to replace it with something or put it in after something?

Comment: You should put my code instead of your command called `p`.

Comment: When i replace it with it i get  "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'prompt' is not defined" I need to define prompt somewhere

Comment: Yes, you need to copy and paste my `prompt` function before other code.